# Connect Orion Context Broker running in RedHat to Raspberry Pi

Tags: audio, redhat, raspberry-pi3, fiware, fiware-orion

I'm using a virtual machine with a RedHat operating system in which I implemented the Orion Context Broker from Fiware and trying to connect to a Raspberry-Pi in order to collect data from a microphone. Can anybody help?

Comment: try to be more specific in your questions. For example what's your specific problem in your case?

Comment: What kind of microphone data are you expecting? What are your specific doubts?

Comment: I need to measure the noise level using Alsa microphone and the data that is collected should be uploaded with Fiware. I have a virtual machine with the Red Hat operatig system and a Raspberry to which I connected the microphone. I don't know how to connect the Pi to the virtual machine.

Comment: It's the first time I'm using the Raspberry and the Fiware platform so sorry for the vague question.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this answer will be very useful, given that the questions is not very precise, but, let's try to help anyway... :)

You could model your sensor as a *context entity* (for instance, `sensor01`) with an *attribute* to hold the noise level (named for instance `noiseLevel`). Then, you could run in your Raspberry an application that measures the noise level using the microphone in a regular time interval, then reporting that attribute measure to Context Broker (running in your RedHat machine) using its RESTful API (NGSIv2). This assumes that there is some kind of network connection between your Rasberrry system and the Red Hat machine where Context Broker is running.

For more information about context management and an Orion introduction I'd recommend you to have a look to [this presentation](https://www.slideshare.net/fermingalan/fiware-managing-context-information-at-large-scale). You will find also in that presentation links to other documents (Orion manuals, etc.) that could help you in your learning path.

Comment: Do you by any chance know how could I make that connection? Thank you so much, I will try to do it. :)

Comment: Which kind of connection do you refer? Physical connection (through wifi or Ethernet)? IP layer connection? Client (at Raspeberry) to Server (Orion, at RedHat system) connection? The question stills being to broad but, whichever the case, I think is rather general and out of the scope of FIWARE topics...

Comment: Ok, I'm going to try and study the platform. Thank you again!

Comment: You can see a guide in the following link: https://alselectro.wordpress.com/2017/02/17/raspberry-pi-3-how-to-connect-with-your-laptop/